# Keyboard shortcut for Jump to Previous View Location (Navigate back/forward) in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is used to go to the location of the last edit.

But I want to jump to whichever location I was most recently at, not necessarily one where I edited anything.

For example, if I jumped to a declaration using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, then I want to go back to where I was before jumping.

Comment: citing the [source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Navigating_to_Recent_Locations.html#previous_edit) of *jump to last edit location* shortcut

Comment: The key does not work for remote in after some Microsoft update on Win 10, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/327866/remote-desktop-sending-ctrl-alt-left-arrow-ctrl-alt-right-arrow-to-the-remote-p)

Answer (score 526, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (*Recent Files* pop-up).

Also check:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (the *Recently Edited Files* pop-up).

Mac users, replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>⌘ (command)</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> with <kbd>⌥ (option)</kbd>.

**Update** In v12.0 it's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd>.

**Update 2** In v14.1 (and possibly earlier) it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

**Update 3** In IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd>

**Update 4** In IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 it's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd>

**Update 5** In IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd>

Comment: Works like a charm ! My stupid video driver had configured these keys for screen rotation, had to disable that first. 
Could you also tell me the shortcut to a function definition within a class by typing the function name in a popup (like `ctrl + n` does for opening a class)

Comment: In v12.0 it's `Alt+shift+left` instead of `Alt+Ctrl+left`

Comment: @Quentin not sure this is true in all cases, mine v12.0 works with Ctrl.

Comment: yep it's probably because of the ubuntu/gnome layout

Comment: Thanks for this! Had same problem as @AnkurVj with screen rotation that threw me off. After disabling that I'm gtg.

Comment: Does anyone know how one can jump to the last view location if said location is in the same file as the current view?

Comment: Crtl + Shift + left, just turns my screen upsidedown  :/

Comment: In Gnome (Linux) you need to disable this keyboard shortcut first.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Down turns my screen upside down.

Comment: To disable some Intel grafics driver shorcuts on windows. Right click the desktop -> select Screen Resolution -> Click Advanced settings -> Click the vendor tab "Intel(R) ..." -> Hit the graphics properties or similar button -> Select Options and Support tab -> Disable Hotkey functionality.

Comment: You can find more information about disabling Intel Graphics Driver shortcuts: http://superuser.com/questions/279756/how-to-disable-the-screen-orientation-hotkeys-in-windows-xp

Comment: None of this jumps back if I am in the same file.

Comment: @PabloJomer I know this was 2 years ago, but thank you this has been bugging me for far too long. Didn't know what was controlling it.

Comment: For me, in Ubuntu, it worked only with Alt+left . Not if I also push Ctrl.

Comment: To disable the rotation shortcuts on my Windows 10: right click desktop | Graphics Options | Hot Keys | Disable.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Left does not work if you're using the Eclipse keymap.

Comment: For Mac users it's Cmd + option(alt) + left arrow for version 2019.3

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + left arrow switches my workspace on Xubuntu!

Comment: For `mac`, it's `option + command + left / right`, or `command + [ / ]`

Comment: On Windows with Word 2016 you can use the Back and Forward commands. I added them to the View panel. The shortcuts are alt + left and alt + right.

Answer (score 123):

The underlying problem is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> are used by window managers to switch workspace and/or OEM utilities to change the screen orientation.

You can change the assignments using 
`File / Settings / Keymap` then `Main Menu / Navigate` find  `Back` and `Forward` and right click to `Add Keyboard Shortcut` to set an alternative key chord.

<kbd>Alt Graph</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Graph</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> works well for me (IDEA 13.1.4 on Ubuntu under IceWM).

Comment: Every system keyboard shortcut should include the super key to separate them from regular applications. Bad design. More Ubuntu conflicts: http://askubuntu.com/questions/412046/unable-to-use-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the "Forward" and "Back" command names. This way I could easily remap them.

Comment: AltGr + Left/Right works for me out of the box in IDEA 2016.3.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: This what i was searching longer time. Its the right fix. Thanks @Steve Pitchers

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['']" 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['']"` 
 [How do I disable Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right?](https://askubuntu.com/a/380461/438856)

Answer (score 71):

**<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>**  -> Go Previous

**<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>** -> Go Next

==========

For OSX, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> are the best choices to go back & forth, Since they are found so near to fingers, avoiding you wrist twisting a bit, one keypress lesser, ideal for users in vim mode.

As the OP requested, this works well with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> which facilitates jumping inside/to the method/variable definition and comes back immediately using <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>. Give a try.

Comment: Also remember that "cmd + [" & "cmd + ]" are a popular pair in Chrome, iTerm, Firefox to go back & forth.

Comment: Nonetheless, all Jetbrains products have highly configurable keymaps, I would have configured Ctr+[ & Ctrl+] for this purpose, even in Windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 28):

For Ubuntu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> work fine.

By default these keys are assigned for Ubuntu's workspace navigation.

You need to disable that by going to :

`System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts Tab > Navigation` and disable `Switch to workspace left` and `Switch to workspace right` by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Or you can choose to change shortcuts in Intellij itself:

```
File > Settings > Keymap > Main menu > Navigate > Back/Forward
```

Answer (score 15):

Q & A is built into Intellij ...

<kbd>CTRL/CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> x 2  <kbd>TYPE</kbd> caret

Comment: @StevePitchers You should see a modal window (bar) popup. Then type 'caret' or move caret to be precise... that will show all the caret movement shortcuts ;-)

Comment: @Eddie B. Thanks: I had also pressed Enter expecting a help browser to appear.  The underlying problem is Ctrl-Alt-Left and -Right is used by  window managers to flip panes and/or OEM utilities to change the screen orientation.  I will add an answer...

Answer (score 12):

For version 14. On mac, it is <kbd>⌥</kbd>(<kbd>alt</kbd>) + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

Mostly the default shortcut key combination is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd>. (I'm using the linux version)

Or you can have a **toolbar** option for it. Enable the tool bar by **View -> Toolbar**. The **Left** and **Right** ***Arrows*** will do the same. If you hover over it then you can see the shortcut key combination also.

[image]
[image]

Just in case the key combination is not working (this can be due to several reasons like you are using a virtual machine, etc) you can change this default key combination, or you can add an extra combination (ex: For **Back/Move to previous** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>Comma</kbd>).

Go to **Settings** **->** **select keymap** (type keymap in the search bar) **-> **Editor Actions -> search for `back` and find Navigate options ->** **change the settings as you prefer.**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

OSX and Android Studio version:

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+ <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>CMD</kbd>+ <kbd>]</kbd>

to move to the previous carret location.

Answer (score 6):

In IntellJ 2017.2,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> navigate between previous locations in the *current* file.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> navigate between previous locations in *all* files.

Comment: is the previous location in current file still supported? What's the name of that action?

Answer (score 6):

Many excellent answers so far, and they do answer the question...But, if you don't want to have to deal with disabling graphics driver's settings, or creating new keyboard mappings, or are developing through a remote session (RDP) or within a VM that intercepts your keystrokes, good-old keyboard navigation still works. Just do <kbd>Alt-N</kbd> to bring up the `Navigate` menu and then hit the <kbd>B</kbd> key.

Please note that you don't hit all keys at the same time. So:

<kbd>Alt-N</kbd> wait <kbd>B</kbd>

This is what I use all the time, for exactly the case that the OP asked about.
Also, this will probably hold through any IntelliJ updates.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the **Keymap** selected.

Keymap: **Mac OS X** <kbd>⌘</kbd> + Left Right Arrow Keys
Keymap: **Mac OS X 10.5+** <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> / <kbd>]</kbd>

I was facing similar problems in Pycharm. To resolve change your Keymap in Preferences.

Answer (score 4):

**Navigate back/forward**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

For Mac users Use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> for backward and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for forward.

Answer (score 4):

Using the following ways using only two keys will be the easier:

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

or

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below to navigate back in 2017.3.4

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Like @itsneo said, I personally find <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> the most convenient ones on a mac. But I can understand if you come from Linux side of things. Then you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> then choose `Keymap` and finally find the keyboard shortcut by type `back` word in search bar at the top right corner.

Answer (score 2):

Intellij 2021.3.2 Basic Shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> = Recent Locations

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> = Recent Files

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> = Find the Class

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> = Navigate the Class

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> = Open the Test Class of the Class

Answer (score 1):

With version 2018.1 the keyboard short cuts for navigation are <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac keyboard using with UNIX OS;

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd> should work for sure.