# Intellij - Go back and forth within a file

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible with a hotkey to navigate back and forth in a class, or file ... rather than between files?

I know it is possible to go back and forth but that happens globally now, using all files. I want to jump between the spots for this file only.

Should not be hard to add on, just filter the history stack for the current active file.

Comment: Not an direct answer to your question, hence the comment, have you reviewed the bookmarking functionality? To try it out enter CTRL-SHIFT-A type `Bookmark` so see that Bookmarking actions. For more info see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/managing-bookmarks.html

Comment: Yeah, i have seen it. It is a project alone to keep up with the bookmark numbers. Thanks for CTRL + SHIFt + A though! Really helpful. I now see that there is a next and previous bookmark, perhaps I don't have to use the mnemonic stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut for Jump to Previous View Location (Navigate back/forward) in IntelliJ Idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441541/keyboard-shortcut-for-jump-to-previous-view-location-navigate-back-forward-in)

Answer (score 7):

No. But it's possible to go to last edited location. If you need it - you can write feature request on [JetBrains tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/).
[image]

**UPD 2019**
Actually there is relatively new shortcut Ctrl + Shift + E to show you recent locations.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a report ID? I'd like to vote on that too but can't find it.

Comment: As written in the issue's comment, Navigate | Back/Forward actions are enough. Still keyboard shortcuts didn't work for me because Ctrl+Alt+Left gets caught by some Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: 4 years and still not implemented... :(