# In PyCharm how to go back to last location?

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

**Edit: my system had global key map which had overridden PyCharm.**
Here's the original question:

I've tried these answers, but nothing happened: [Keyboard shortcut for Jump to Previous View Location (Navigate back/forward) in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441541/keyboard-shortcut-for-jump-to-previous-view-location-in-intellij-idea)

For example:

1. I'm navigating to a function body,
2. put the cursor on a function call,
3. click <kbd>F12</kbd> ("go to definition")
4. from the new location (the function's body), how do I return to the function call?

I've tried these, but they didn't do anything:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>      <-- this is my default mapping
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>
- don't try that on linux:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>

Or maybe <kbd>F12</kbd> ("go to def") isn't "strong enough" to trigger a location-change event?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic / PyCharm 2021.2>>>>>>Alt+Shift+Left

Answer (score 73, accepted):

All in all, it has nothing with PyCharm;

In my case, there was a global key combo of another program, that masked <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Left</kbd>

I solve it by remapping "file > settings > keymap > main menu > navigate > back".

I chose <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, which intuitively feels likes web browsers "back" behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, it works. But alt+left was already taken for me to another action.

Comment: This made me discover "button 4" on the mouse, also mentioned in the answer from @Hawklaz below.

Answer (score 141):

Under ArchLinux with PyCharm CE 3.1 works the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>.

This is the way I find out the combination:

1. *(Right click) Go To -> Implementation(s)*
2. <kbd>Double Shift</kbd> -> *Back*

   [image]
3. There is an option `Back` in the section `Actions`
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

   [image]
5. And then the cursor comes back

Comment: thank you for the useful "actions" tip (upvoted, fwiw), but as i mention - ctrl-alt-left didn't work for me, hence, irrelevant.  see my answer

Comment: just a warning - on windows 7, ctrl-alt-left arrow rotates the screen!

Comment: @Melanie, It is, probably, because of your graphics settings. As far as I remember, there is some shortcuts for rotating / mirroring / duplicating / etc. shortcuts in Intel Graphics module.

Comment: In version 2017.2.3 (probably before as well) this has been changed to alt-shift-left

Comment: Both ctrl+alt+left and shift+alt+left works for me (pycharm 2017 2.3)

Comment: Unsurprisingly, you can then also "go forward again" using ctrl-alt-right.

Comment: On pycharm 2020 (linux) I have `Shift-Alt-Left` (not `Ctrl-Alt-Left` anymore) as default for the `Back` action.

Comment: `Back` does switching tabs for me. Just like `Ctrl+PgUp`, `Ctrl+PgDn` do. If my files are already opened it doesn't switch just `back` to the previous code (like if I'm dropping into function Declaration). Sad thing, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 57):

In mac OS X (atleast in El Capitan) it is  by default   <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> 
to go back to the previous location.

update: if that doesn't work also try <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd>

Comment: how do you that on a small keyboard with direct [ stroke ? I am on a mac book air 11 inch

Comment: option+cmd+left arrow worked for me, nice!

Answer (score 41):

**Update for year 2016 to at least 2020.1.1:**

In PyCharm 2016+ on windows the correct default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/navigating-to-next-previous-change.html

Be warned that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> will rotate your entire screen on Windows 10. If you're reading this with your head cocked sideways, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> will get you back vertical!

Comment: But navigating to the previous change is different than navigating to the previous location.  When I'm reading my code to understand it, I don't want to make a change to it.

Comment: Still true in PyCharm 2020.1.1

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>

The above works with PyCharm 2016.3.2 if you select the keymap "default for GNOME".

Answer (score 15):

#### PyCharm 2019.1+

This version of PyCharm has a new functionality called [**Recent Locations**](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#v2019-1-ide-improvements). This is useful when you find yourself needing to move back and forth between different locations in the code.

You can use the *Recent Locations popup* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>⇧</kbd> +<kbd>E</kbd> on macOS) to get you to your destination quicker.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

On macOS (Sierra; 10.12.6) and PyCharm 2017.3.1 (Professional Edition; built on December 13, 2017), if you're using the Go To -> Declaration (⌘+B), you can jump back and forth using ⌘+⌥+◀ or ▶.

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> is overridden in for switching to left *workspace*. I don't use workspaces at all so I cancelled that shortcut in **System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Navigation -> Switch to workspace left**.

Answer (score 5):

I have the following environment:

1. Ubuntu 16.04 (GNOME)
2. VNC viewer.
3. PyCharm 2019.1 (Community edition)

In my case, when examing the "Back" navigation settings it indeed indicated that it is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> , YET it did not work. What **DOES** work is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>.

Comment: Same on PopOS/Ubuntu based distro, PyCharm 2020.3

Answer (score 5):

Since I don't have commenting rights, answering here. Note that if you have side buttons on your mouse, you can also use `Mouse button 4` and `Mouse button 5` to move to previous and next cursor position respectively. Just in case you don't want to remap your keys in Pycharm since Ctrl+Alt+Left doesn't seem to work on for me on Windows 10 with `Pycharm 2020.2.3`

Have a look at the key mapping based on [@Berry Tsakala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25104311/11542679)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solutions don't go with mac. But I found that <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> takes you to location that you were working with.

To further explain, if you have pressed <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse click</kbd> to navigate to a function, pressing the above combination takes to directly to the call.

Answer (score 3):

Search for `Back` in the `Settings` ‒> `Keymap`, click on it and change it for what you want ‒ should help on all systems.

I use Ubuntu so the default was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>, but this combination is already in use by the system.

Answer (score 0):

This page from the Pycharm documentation is quite useful for this... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html

Here's the relevant table...
[image]