# Executing multiple lines of input in pycharm console from first line

Tags: python, pycharm, ipython

When working with the interactive console in PyCharm (via IPython), is there any way to execute the currently loaded multiline statement from not the last line?

In Jupyter's QtConsole, this can be done by pressing `Shift`+`Enter` on any line of  input. i.e.

```
In [1]: print("line 1")
   ...  print("line 2")
```

Can be evaluated by pressing `Shift`+`Enter` regardless of where the caret is located. In the IPython-based interactive console in PyCharm, pressing `Shift`+`Enter` creates a new line below the current one and moves the caret to it, while `Ctrl`+`Enter` splits the line at the current caret position.

I could not find any settings that control this behavior; perhaps it is a limitation of IPython?

EDIT: In the regular IPython REPL, `Alt`+`Enter` accomplishes what I'm after, but this does not work in the PyCharm console, even after removing the default  shortcut assigned to that keystroke ("Show Intention Actions")

Comment: I too am looking for the answer. There is an option in the Pycharm keymap to "Execute Current Statement in Multiline Console" which is set to CTRL Enter but somehow nothing happens when I press that in console.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, never did!

Comment: Fyi, CTRL Enter not working was just submitted as a bug, so maybe we'll finally get this issue fixed!

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this link can help you:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/loading-code-from-editor-into-console.html

pressing Alt + Shift + E on a selection will execute the selected code in the console.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but it's not exactly what I'm after. Basically, I use the console to iteratively debug, and when running a wrapped command (like modifying part of a long XPath), having to always put the cursor at the end of the block of code is time consuming and not a great workflow.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no direct shortcut for this, at least you can do it with a workaround:

- Position to start with (call it PositionEND, since it is the end of the selection that you must paradoxically *start* with): Put the cursor in the *end position up to which* you want to run your code.
- Make an edit of whatever choice, it could be just pressing a letter, and then revert the edit. This puts this position as the last edit position in memory. This "last edit"-trick is to get back to that position after the execution of the following selection.
- Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Pos1</kbd>, or if you want to run all, take <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> instead.
- Execute the selection with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.
- Get back to the "last edit"-trick position <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to go to the last edit according to the question body at [Keyboard shortcut for Jump to Previous View Location (Navigate back/forward) in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441541/keyboard-shortcut-for-jump-to-previous-view-location-navigate-back-forward-in)

If you have selected some code, and you want to get to the bottom of the selection; or if you have just applied <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and you realise that you have forgotten to edit something at PositonEND in order to use the trick above with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, and you want to go back to PositionEND, you must simply copy / cut and paste the selected code, that will put your cursor to the end of the selection:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> would work as well)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

*By the way, if you are in somewhat else than in the editor and you want to turn back, do not click inside the editor, but just click on the needed ".py"-tab then so that your latest selection information does not get lost.*

---

If

- you can take a "risk" / try your luck /
- coming back to a nearby place is enough,

you may use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>← (Left Arrow)</kbd>, though this is very often not helping you to get to that exact previous cursor place, being confusingly called: "Jump to Previous View Location". It does not always do what you would expect (I think).